# WSO2 carbon app deployment for multiple tenants

Tags: wso2

I am trying to develop a data integration service which will be used in multi-tenant mode. We are exploring different solutions available, and WSO2 is one of them. I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1 (Carbon).

I have created two tenants from superuser's management console, and deployed the *.car file from each tenant's login.

My understanding of multi-tenancy was that single deployement is done, and multiple tenants/users of the system access the same deployed service without interferring each other or getting blocked.

But here, I have to deploy the same carbon application for each tenant (twice in my case) from management console. How is it multi-tenant then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have didn't clearly understand the what is an tenant. Consider tenant as a separate organization. For e.g if you take Alphabet, you have Google, Youtube, Maps, etc... Those are your tenants. So each tenant can have their own set of apps.

If you want all the tenant users to access a particular app I think you can mark that as a SaaS app. That way any user from any tenant can access that particular app.

Hope that gives you a clear idea.
You can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Multi-tenant+Architecture for more details about tenancy concept in WSO2

Comment: Ok. So mine is a SaaS app. How can I configure multi-tenancy in my "Composite Application" which I am developing using WSO2 developer studio. I googled around and found the following link which talks about developing a multi-tenant SaaS web app using WSO2:

https://wso2.com/library/blog-post/2013/09/creating-a-saas-app-with-the-multi-tenant-carbon-framework-step-1/

It says that we need to set carbon.saas.tenants parameter in web.xml with the appropriate tenant scope.
Is there similar setting which needs to be done for "composite apps"?